# How to setup Apache XAMMP as web server in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2017.2.1 and `$_POST` does not work.

A number of sources suggested that I use an external web server instead of the PhpStorm built-in web server. I have XAMMP installed and I'm using php 5.6.

Please give me detailed steps on how to setup Apache XAMMP as my web server.

Comment: *"I am using PhpStorm 2017.2.1 and $_POST does not work"* Try 2017.2.2 -- it should be fixed there (if I'm reading the change log correctly). Other than that -- it's very simple -- just set it up as a Deployment entry (the URL). See the link in @FitraZulFahmi answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE) site. You can follow the step from there.